# Making a ball jump just once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm working on a unity project that works something like the roll the ball project tutorial on the unity page, basically i want the ball to jump just once, to do that i already implemented the logic, but something fails and i can't figure out.

**Here is my code**

```
public bool inAir = false;


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){
    if (other.gameObject.tag=="Terrain") 
        inAir = false;
        else
        inAir = true;
    }

void FixedUpdate () {
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    Debug.Log (inAir);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space") && !inAir){
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0,jump,0));
    }

}
```

**resuming:** i just added a inAir variable that is set to false at begin because the ball starts at the floor, then i check the colision enter if the object is in colision with a other object that i changed the tag to Terrain inAir is false, else it is true, then at the end of the FixedUpdate  check if the key is space and if the ball is not in the air just in this case the ball can jump

**What is happening:** the variable inAir is always false, it enters the first if always, and stay always false, it never enter the else, so what is wrong here?

Comment: It never collides with anything else?

Comment: You may want to set `inAir` to true once the player has jumped (right after that second `AddForce` call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting  `inAir` to `true` or `false` in the `OnCollisionEnter` function, implement `OnCollisionExit` too then set it in both functions. This is more reliable.

```
public bool inAir = false;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Terrain")
        inAir = false;
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Terrain")
        inAir = true;
}
```

Comment: worked great, thanks pal, you changed the values but i got the answer :D

Comment: Yeah just noticed that. Fixed it and you are welcome!